# Laravel 7 variable not passed to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a strange error:

i pass a simple var from controller to view like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\BE;


class User extends Controller
{

  // some stuff here

    public function sendPasswordReminder(Request $request) {

        return response()
            ->view('BE.user.passwordreset', ['name' => 'James'], 200);

        // very simple, nothing special here, also tried return view() stuff
     }

}
```

and an absolutly basic blade:

```
@extends('BE.templates.main')
@section('content')
   {{ $name }}
@endsection
```

and i get the response

```
Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Undefined variable: name (View: /Users/modii/Work/l7/distr/resources/views/BE/user/passwordreset.blade.php)
```

i ended up with this absolute basic version while trying to figure out what is wrong. this should be very basic. its not working. tried to clear cache both with artisan and manually. no result.

i have NO IDEA what could be wrong. If anyone has an idea...

Comment: I think problem on your route. Just check it with `return "test";` do you get the output?

Comment: the rout is ok, if i remove the var it returns the view. 

to answer the second one:

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\BE;

use App\Events\RequestsActivationMail;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
......
```

Comment: Check it with `return "test";` you get the **test** output?

Comment: damn it...


  public function sendPasswordReminder(Request $request) {



        return "test";

} --- and the SAME error. what the... the routing is:

    Route::post('/reset-password', 'BE\User@sendPasswordReminder')->name('adm_resetPasswordProcess');

Comment: Yeah, I know the problem is on your route. Happy coding :)

Comment: sorry, my mistake copy/pasting, wrong func. but no, the problem still there...

Comment: Please update your code, so can find the error

Comment: so

 public function sendPasswordReminder(Request $request) {

        return "test"; }

still returning wrong output...

Comment: You got this error after submit the `form`?

Comment: yupp. it comes up on POST. got 2 routs, one for get and one fo post:

    Route::get('/reset-password', function () { return view('BE.user.passwordreset'); })->name('adm_resetPassword');
    Route::post('/reset-password', 'BE\User@sendPasswordReminder')->name('adm_resetPasswordProcess');

Comment: Do you please update your question, with both GET, POST route and its controller code

Comment: Guys, my stupidity. i tested post form submit with postman. for some reason (dont know why)  the GET rout runned.

Thats why i like symfony's annotation routing better..

thanks for leading me in the good direction. solved.

Comment: Nice to hear that. Happy coding :)